# How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization

This loop runs at one iteration per 3 cycles on Intel Conroe/Merom, bottlenecked on `imul` throughput as expected.  But on Haswell/Skylake, it runs at one iteration per 11 cycles, apparently because `setnz al` has a dependency on the last `imul`.

```
; synthetic micro-benchmark to test partial-register renaming
    mov     ecx, 1000000000
.loop:                 ; do{
    imul    eax, eax     ; a dep chain with high latency but also high throughput
    imul    eax, eax
    imul    eax, eax

    dec     ecx          ; set ZF, independent of old ZF.  (Use sub ecx,1 on Silvermont/KNL or P4)
    setnz   al           ; ****** Does this depend on RAX as well as ZF?
    movzx   eax, al
    jnz  .loop         ; }while(ecx);
```

If `setnz al` depends on `rax`, the 3ximul/setcc/movzx sequence forms a loop-carried dependency chain.  If not, each `setcc`/`movzx`/3x`imul` chain is independent, forked off from the `dec` that updates the loop counter.  The 11c per iteration measured on HSW/SKL is perfectly explained by a latency bottleneck: 3x3c(imul) + 1c(read-modify-write by setcc) + 1c(movzx within the same register).

---

**Off topic: avoiding these (intentional) bottlenecks**

I was going for understandable / predictable behaviour to isolate partial-reg stuff, not optimal performance.

For example, `xor`-zero / set-flags / `setcc` is better anyway (in this case, `xor eax,eax` / `dec ecx` / `setnz al`).  That breaks the dep on eax on all CPUs (except early P6-family like PII and PIII), still avoids partial-register merging penalties, and saves 1c of `movzx` latency.  It also uses one fewer ALU uop on CPUs that [handle xor-zeroing in the register-rename stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/33668295#33668295).  See that link for more about using xor-zeroing with `setcc`.

Note that AMD, Intel Silvermont/KNL, and P4, don't do partial-register renaming at all.  It's only a feature in Intel P6-family CPUs and its descendant, Intel Sandybridge-family, but seems to be getting phased out.

gcc unfortunately does tend to use `cmp` / `setcc al` / `movzx eax,al` where it could have used `xor` instead of `movzx` [(Godbolt compiler-explorer example)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'//+gcc+uses+xor/cmp/setcc+in+a+simple+case%0Aint+boolean(int+a)+%7B+return+a!!%3D5%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0A//+When+things+get+complex+enough,+gcc+uses+setcc/movzx.%0A//+But+fortunately+into+a+register+that+was+already+part+of+the+same+dep+chain%0A//+clang+uses+R8%0Aunsigned+int+countmatch(unsigned+int+arr%5B%5D,+unsigned+int+key)%0A%7B%0A++++unsigned+count+%3D+0%3B%0A++++for+(int+i%3D0%3B+i%3C1024+%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++//+changing+%60key%60+to+%607%60+doesn!'t+get+gcc+to+use+xor/cmp/setcc:+It!'s+not+trying+to+avoid+REX+prefixes,+maybe+just+some+register-pressure+threshold%0A++++++++count+%2B%3D+((arr%5Bi%5D+%26+key)+!!%3D+5)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+count%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+we+can+even+convince+gcc+and+clang+to+do+%0A//+%22dangerous%22+things+with+partial+registers%0A//+by+combining+boolean+conditions%0Aunsigned+int+doubletmatch(unsigned+int+arr%5B%5D,+unsigned+int+key)%0A%7B%0A++++unsigned+count+%3D+0%3B%0A++++for+(int+i%3D0%3B+i%3C1024+%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++//+gcc+uses+a+32-bit+OR+to+combine+setcc+results+even+with+-march%3Dcore2%0A++++++++//+causing+a+partial-register+stall.++(Even+with+old+gcc)%0A++++++++count+%2B%3D+(arr%5Bi%5D+%3D%3D+key)+%7C+(arr%5Bi%5D+%3D%3D+~key)%3B%0A++++++++//+clang+-m32+uses+dl+and+dh,+which+is+also+problematic%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+count%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A//+compilers+don!'t+spend+an+instruction+breaking+the+dep+on+the+setcc+destination,%0A//+even+with+-march%3Dbdver2+(Piledriver)+where+it!'s+known+to+have+one.%0A//+This+doesn!'t+usually+come+up,+since+trivial+functions+usually+inline.%0Achar+narrow_boolean(int+a)+%7B+return+a!!%3D5%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0A%23if+0%0A//+gcc+uses+setcc/movzx+for+these,+but+only+in+32-bit+mode.%0A//+I+think+because+of+the+extra+work+of+loading+args+from+the+stack%0A//+In+this+case+there!'s+no+actual+register+pressure,%0A//+because+the+pointers+are+dead+by+the+time+we+need+them.%0Aint+foo(unsigned+int+%26a,+unsigned+int+%26b)+%7B%0A++++return+a+%2B+(a!!%3Db)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aextern+int+extfunc(unsigned)%3B%0Aunsigned+int+bar(unsigned+int+a,+unsigned+int+b)+%7B%0A++++a+*%3D+b%3B%0A++++b+*%3D+a%3B%0A++++a+*%3D+b%3B%0A++++b+*%3D+a%3B%0A++++//int+r+%3D+extfunc(a)%3B%0A++++return+a+%2B+(a!!%3Db)%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:37.151279838941626,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g71,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-Wall+-O3++-mtune%3Dhaswell+-fno-tree-vectorize',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:30.12953615077989,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang400,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1502600537666:(undefined:(legend:!(1590,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery321081933210614779781:(display:''),sizzle1502600537666:(undefined:(legend:!(1590,0,'1')))),length:1))),options:'-Wall+-O3+-mtune%3Dhaswell++-fno-tree-vectorize+-fno-unroll-loops',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:32.7191840102785,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), while clang uses xor-zero/cmp/setcc unless you combine multiple boolean conditions like `count += (a==b) | (a==~b)`.

The xor/dec/setnz version runs at 3.0c per iteration on Skylake, Haswell, and Core2 (bottlenecked on `imul` throughput).  `xor`-zeroing breaks the dependency on the old value of `eax` on all out-of-order CPUs other than PPro/PII/PIII/early-Pentium-M (where it still avoids partial-register merging penalties but doesn't break the dep).  [Agner Fog's microarch guide describes this](http://agner.org/optimize/).  Replacing the xor-zeroing with `mov eax,0` slows it down to one per 4.78 cycles on Core2: [2-3c stall (in the front-end?) to insert a partial-reg merging uop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031671/why-are-mov-ah-bh-and-mov-al-bl-together-much-faster-than-single-instruction-mo/35175245#35175245) when `imul` reads `eax` after `setnz al`.

Also, I used `movzx eax, al` which defeats mov-elimination, just like `mov rax,rax` does.  (IvB, HSW, and SKL can rename `movzx eax, bl` with 0 latency, but Core2 can't).  This makes everything equal across Core2 / SKL, except for the partial-register behaviour.

---

The Core2 behaviour is consistent with [Agner Fog's microarch guide](http://agner.org/optimize/), but the HSW/SKL behaviour isn't.  From section 11.10 for Skylake, and same for previous Intel uarches:

> Different parts of a general purpose register can be stored in different temporary registers in order to remove false dependences.

He unfortunately doesn't have time to do detailed testing for every new uarch to re-test assumptions, so this change in behaviour slipped through the cracks.

Agner does describe a merging uop being inserted (without stalling) for high8 registers (AH/BH/CH/DH) on Sandybridge through Skylake, and for low8/low16 on SnB.  (I've unfortunately been spreading mis-information in the past, and saying that Haswell can merge AH for free.  I skimmed Agner's Haswell section too quickly, and didn't notice the later paragraph about high8 registers.  Let me know if you see my wrong comments on other posts, so I can delete them or add a correction.  I will try to at least find and edit my answers where I've said this.)

---

My actual questions: **How *exactly* do partial registers really behave on Skylake?**

**Is everything the same from IvyBridge to Skylake, including the high8 extra latency?**

[Intel's optimization manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf#page=129) is not specific about which CPUs have false dependencies for what (although it does mention that some CPUs have them), and leaves out things like reading AH/BH/CH/DH (high8 registers) adding extra latency even when they haven't been modified.

If there's any P6-family (Core2/Nehalem) behaviour that Agner Fog's microarch guide doesn't describe, that would be interesting too, but I should probably limit the scope of this question to just Skylake or Sandybridge-family.

---

**My Skylake test data**, from putting `%rep 4` short sequences inside a small `dec ebp/jnz` loop that runs 100M or 1G iterations.  I measured cycles with Linux `perf` the same way as [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all/44193770#44193770), on the same hardware (desktop Skylake i7 6700k).

Unless otherwise noted, each instruction runs as 1 fused-domain uop, using an ALU execution port.  (Measured with [`ocperf.py stat -e ...,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread`](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools)).  This detects (absence of) mov-elimination and extra merging uops.

The "4 per cycle" cases are an extrapolation to the infinitely-unrolled case.  Loop overhead takes up some of the front-end bandwidth, but anything better than 1 per cycle is an indication that register-renaming avoided the [write-after-write output dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming#Data_hazards), and that the uop isn't handled internally as a read-modify-write.

**Writing to AH only**:  prevents the loop from executing from the loopback buffer (aka the Loop Stream Detector (LSD)).  Counts for `lsd.uops` are exactly 0 on HSW, and tiny on SKL (around 1.8k) and don't scale with the loop iteration count.  Probably those counts are from some kernel code.  When loops do run from the LSD, `lsd.uops ~= uops_issued` to within measurement noise.  Some loops alternate between LSD or no-LSD (e.g when they might not fit into the uop cache if decode starts in the wrong place), but I didn't run into that while testing this.

- repeated `mov ah, bh` and/or `mov ah, bl` runs at 4 per cycle.  It takes an ALU uop, so it's not eliminated like `mov eax, ebx` is.
- repeated `mov ah, [rsi]` runs at 2 per cycle (load throughput bottleneck).
- repeated `mov ah, 123` runs at 1 per cycle.  (A [dep-breaking `xor eax,eax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/33668295#33668295) inside the loop removes the bottleneck.)
- repeated `setz ah` or `setc ah` runs at 1 per cycle.  (A dep-breaking `xor eax,eax` lets it bottleneck on p06 throughput for `setcc` and the loop branch.)

  **Why does writing `ah` with an instruction that would normally use an ALU execution unit have a false dependency on the old value, while `mov r8, r/m8` doesn't (for reg or memory src)?**  (And what about `mov r/m8, r8`?  Surely it doesn't matter which of the two opcodes you use for reg-reg moves?)
- repeated `add ah, 123` runs at 1 per cycle, as expected.
- repeated `add dh, cl` runs at 1 per cycle.
- repeated `add dh, dh` runs at 1 per cycle.
- repeated `add dh, ch` runs at 0.5 per cycle.  Reading [ABCD]H is special when they're "clean" (in this case, RCX is not recently modified at all).

**Terminology**: All of these leave AH (or DH) "**dirty**", i.e. in need of merging (with a merging uop) when the rest of the register is read (or in some other cases).  i.e. that AH is renamed separately from RAX, if I'm understanding this correctly.  "**clean**" is the opposite.  There are many ways to clean a dirty register, the simplest being `inc eax` or `mov eax, esi`.

**Writing to AL only**: These loops do run from the LSD: `uops_issue.any` ~= `lsd.uops`.

- repeated `mov al, bl` runs at 1 per cycle.  An occasional dep-breaking `xor eax,eax` per group lets OOO execution bottleneck on uop throughput, not latency.
- repeated `mov al, [rsi]` runs at 1 per cycle, as a micro-fused ALU+load uop.  (uops_issued=4G + loop overhead, uops_executed=8G + loop overhead).
  A dep-breaking `xor eax,eax` before a group of 4 lets it bottleneck on 2 loads per clock.
- repeated `mov al, 123` runs at 1 per cycle.
- repeated `mov al, bh` runs at 0.5 per cycle.  (1 per 2 cycles).  Reading [ABCD]H is special.
- `xor eax,eax` + 6x `mov al,bh` + `dec ebp/jnz`: 2c per iter, bottleneck on 4 uops per clock for the front-end.
- repeated `add dl, ch` runs at 0.5 per cycle.  (1 per 2 cycles).  Reading [ABCD]H apparently creates extra latency for `dl`.
- repeated `add dl, cl` runs at 1 per cycle.

I think a write to a low-8 reg behaves as a RMW blend into the full reg, like `add eax, 123` would be, but it doesn't trigger a merge if `ah` is dirty.  So (other than ignoring `AH` merging) it behaves the same as on CPUs that don't do partial-reg renaming at all.  It seems `AL` is never renamed separately from `RAX`?

- `inc al`/`inc ah` pairs can run in parallel.
- `mov ecx, eax` inserts a merging uop if `ah` is "dirty", but the actual `mov` is renamed.  This is what [Agner Fog describes](http://agner.org/optimize/) for IvyBridge and later.
- repeated `movzx  eax, ah` runs at one per 2 cycles.  (Reading high-8 registers after writing full regs has extra latency.)
- `movzx ecx, al` has zero latency and doesn't take an execution port on HSW and SKL.  (Like what Agner Fog describes for IvyBridge, but he says HSW doesn't rename movzx).
- `movzx ecx, cl` has 1c latency and takes an execution port.  ([mov-elimination never works for the `same,same` case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all/44193770#44193770), only between different architectural registers.)

  A loop that inserts a merging uop every iteration can't run from the LSD (loop buffer)?

I don't think there's anything special about AL/AH/RAX vs. B*, C*, DL/DH/RDX.  I have tested some with partial regs in other registers (even though I'm mostly showing `AL`/`AH` for consistency), and have never noticed any difference.

**How can we explain all of these observations with a sensible model of how the microarch works internally?**

---

Related:  Partial **flag** issues are different from partial **register** issues.  See [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter/36510865#36510865) for some super-weird stuff with `shr r32,cl` (and even `shr r32,2` on Core2/Nehalem: don't read flags from a shift other than by 1).

See also [Problems with ADC/SBB and INC/DEC in tight loops on some CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084204/problems-with-adc-sbb-and-inc-dec-in-tight-loops-on-some-cpus) for partial-flag stuff in `adc` loops.

Comment: It was hard writing this up in a Q&A format.  That took longer than the actual experimentation.  But I think I managed to create something that could usefully be answered by someone else, with a question that isn't too simple.  IDK if putting most of this into the answer would have been "better", but I wanted the question title to summarize the important part.

Comment: Your labor of love was certainly useful, though. This cleared up some confusion I had. I was not aware that HSW/SKL no longer issued the merge uop after ALU ops writing partial registers.

My copy of the manual from May 2020 states, "Beginning with Sandy Bridge microarchitecture and *all subsequent generations* of Intel Core microarchitecture, partial register access is handled in hardware by inserting a micro-op that merges the partial register with the full register in the following cases" (emphasis mine). It fails to clarify that this applies to MOV but not to other instructions.

Comment: Why does repeated `mov al, 123` runs at 1 per cycle? but `movl eax, 123` repeated runs at 4cycles / iteration? Nevermind, its because `mov al, 123` is not dependency breaking.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Other answers welcome to address Sandybridge and IvyBridge in more detail.
I don't have access to that hardware.

---

I haven't found any partial-reg behaviour differences between HSW and SKL.
On Haswell and Skylake, everything I've tested so far supports this model:

**AL is never renamed separately from RAX** (or r15b from r15).  So if you never touch the high8 registers (AH/BH/CH/DH), everything behaves exactly like on a CPU with no partial-reg renaming (e.g. AMD).

Write-only access to AL merges into RAX, with a dependency on RAX.  For loads into AL, this is a micro-fused ALU+load uop that executes on p0156, which is one of the strongest pieces of evidence that it's truly merging on every write, and not just doing some fancy double-bookkeeping as Agner speculated.

Agner (and Intel) say Sandybridge can require a merging uop for AL, so it probably is renamed separately from RAX.  For SnB, [Intel's optimization manual (section 3.5.2.4 Partial Register Stalls)](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf#page=129) says

> SnB (not necessarily later uarches) inserts a merging uop in the following cases:
>
> - After a write to one of the registers AH, BH, CH or DH and before a
>   following read of the 2-, 4- or 8-byte form of the same register. In
>   these cases a merge micro-op is inserted. **The insertion consumes a
>   full allocation cycle in which other micro-ops cannot be allocated.**
> - After a micro-op with a destination register of 1 or 2 bytes, which is
>   not a source of the instruction (or the register's bigger form), and
>   before a following read of a 2-,4- or 8-byte form of the same
>   register. In these cases **the merge micro-op is part of the flow**.

I think they're saying that on SnB, `add al,bl` will RMW the full RAX instead of renaming it separately, because one of the source registers is (part of) RAX.  My guess is that this doesn't apply for a load like `mov al, [rbx + rax]`; `rax` in an addressing mode probably doesn't count as a source.

I haven't tested whether high8 merging uops still have to issue/rename on their own on HSW/SKL.  That would make the front-end impact equivalent to 4 uops (since that's the issue/rename pipeline width).

- There is no way to break a dependency involving AL without writing EAX/RAX.  `xor al,al` doesn't help, and neither does `mov al, 0`.
- **`movzx ebx, al` has [zero latency (renamed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all/44193770#44193770), and needs no execution unit.**  (i.e. mov-elimination works on HSW and SKL).  **It triggers merging of AH if it's dirty**, which I guess is necessary for it to work without an ALU.  It's probably not a coincidence that Intel dropped low8 renaming in the same uarch that introduced mov-elimination.  (Agner Fog's micro-arch guide has a mistake here, saying that zero-extended moves are not eliminated on HSW or SKL, only IvB.)
- `movzx eax, al` is *not* eliminated at rename.  mov-elimination on Intel never works for same,same.  `mov rax,rax` isn't eliminated either, even though it doesn't have to zero-extend anything.  (Although there'd be no point to giving it special hardware support, because it's just a no-op, unlike `mov eax,eax`).  Anyway, prefer moving between two separate architectural registers when zero-extending, whether it's with a 32-bit `mov` or an 8-bit `movzx`.
- `movzx eax, bx` is *not* eliminated at rename on HSW or SKL.  It has 1c latency and uses an ALU uop.  Intel's optimization manual only mentions zero-latency for 8-bit movzx (and points out that `movzx r32, high8` is never renamed).

---

#### High-8 regs can be renamed separately from the rest of the register, and do need merging uops.

- Write-only access to `ah` with `mov ah, reg8` or `mov ah, [mem8]` do rename AH, with no dependency on the old value, unlike with mov-immediate.  These are both instructions that wouldn't normally need an ALU uop for the 32-bit version.  (But `mov ah, bl` is *not* eliminated; it does need a p0156 ALU uop so that might be a coincidence).
- a RMW of AH (like `inc ah`) dirties it (so it's renamed separately and needs a merging uop if AX, EAX, or RAX is read later, including as part of writing AX.)
- `setcc ah` depends on the old `ah`, but still dirties it.  I think `mov ah, imm8` is the same, but haven't tested as many corner cases.

(Unexplained: a loop involving `setcc ah` can sometimes run from the LSD, see the `rcr` loop at the end of this post.  Maybe as long as `ah` is clean at the *end* of the loop, it can use the LSD?).

If `ah` is dirty, `setcc ah` merges into the renamed `ah`, rather than forcing a merge into `rax`.  e.g.  `%rep 4` (`inc al` / `test ebx,ebx` / `setcc ah` / `inc al` / `inc ah`) generates no merging uops, and only runs in about 8.7c (latency of 8 `inc al` slowed down by resource conflicts from the uops for `ah`.  Also the `inc ah` / `setcc ah` dep chain).

I think what's going on here is that `setcc r8` is always implemented as a read-modify-write.  Intel probably decided that it wasn't worth having a write-only `setcc` uop to optimize the `setcc ah` case, since it's very rare for compiler-generated code to `setcc ah`.  (But see the godbolt link in the question: clang4.0 with `-m32` will do so.)

- Reading AX, EAX, or RAX triggers a merge uop (which takes up front-end issue/rename bandwidth).  Probably the RAT (Register Allocation Table) tracks the high-8-dirty state for the architectural R[ABCD]X, and even after a write to AH retires, the AH data is stored in a separate physical register from RAX.  Even with 256 NOPs between writing AH and reading EAX,  there is an extra merging uop. (ROB size=224 on SKL, so this guarantees that the `mov ah, 123` was retired).  Detected with uops_issued/executed perf counters, which clearly show the difference.
- Read-modify-write of AL (e.g. `inc al`) merges for free, as part of the ALU uop.  (Only tested with a few simple uops, like `add`/`inc`, not `div r8` or `mul r8`).  Again, no merging uop is triggered even if AH is dirty.
- Write-only to EAX/RAX (like `lea eax, [rsi + rcx]` or [`xor eax,eax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and)) clears the AH-dirty state (no merging uop).
- Write-only to AX (`mov ax, 1` or `mov ax, bx`) triggers a merge of AH first.  I guess instead of special-casing this, it runs like any other RMW of AX/RAX.
- `xor ah,ah` has 1c latency, is not dep-breaking, and still needs an execution port.  `mov ah,0` is the same; like with `setcc`, perhaps mov-immediate to 8-bit reg isn't special-cased for high-8 registers, unlike with `mov reg,reg`
- Read and/or write of AL does not force a merge, so AH can stay dirty (and be used independently in a separate dep chain).  (e.g. `add  ah, cl` / `add   al, dl` can run at 2 IPC, one pair per clock (bottlenecked on add latency).

---

**Making AH dirty prevents a loop from running from the LSD** (the loop-buffer), even when there are no merging uops.  The LSD is when the CPU recycles uops in the queue that feeds the issue/rename stage.  (Called the IDQ).

Inserting merging uops is a bit like inserting stack-sync uops for the stack-engine.  Intel's optimization manual says that SnB's LSD can't run loops with mismatched `push`/`pop`, which makes sense, but it implies that it *can* run loops with balanced `push`/`pop`.  That's not what I'm seeing on SKL: even balanced `push`/`pop` prevents running from the LSD (e.g. `push rax` / `pop rdx` / `times 6 imul rax, rdx`.  (There may be a real difference between SnB's LSD and HSW/SKL:  [SnB may just "lock down" the uops in the IDQ instead of repeating them multiple times, so a 5-uop loop takes 2 cycles to issue instead of 1.25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311872/is-performance-reduced-when-executing-loops-whose-uop-count-is-not-a-multiple-of).)  Anyway, it appears that HSW/SKL can't use the LSD when a high-8 register is dirty, or when it contains stack-engine uops.

This behaviour may be related to a [an erratum in SKL](https://hothardware.com/news/critical-flaw-in-intel-skylake-and-kaby-lake-hyperthreading-discovered-requiring-bios-microcode-fix):

> [SKL150: Short Loops Which Use AH/BH/CH/DH Registers May Cause Unpredictable System Behaviour](https://www3.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/desktop-6th-gen-core-family-spec-update.pdf)

> Problem: Under complex micro-architectural conditions, short loops of less than 64 instruction that use AH, BH, CH, or DH registers as well as their corresponding wider registers (e.g. RAX, EAX, or AX for AH) may cause unpredictable system behaviour.  This can only happen when both logical processors on the same physical processor are active.

This may also be related to Intel's optimization manual statement that SnB at least has to issue/rename an AH-merge uop in a cycle by itself.  That's a weird difference for the front-end.

My Linux kernel log says `microcode: sig=0x506e3, pf=0x2, revision=0x84`.
Arch Linux's `intel-ucode` package just provides the update, [you have to edit config files to actually have it loaded](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/microcode#Enabling_Intel_microcode_updates). So **my Skylake testing was on an i7-6700k with microcode revision 0x84, which [doesn't include the fix for SKL150](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2017/06/msg00308.html)**.  It matches the Haswell behaviour in every case I tested, IIRC.  (e.g. both Haswell and my SKL can run the `setne ah` / `add ah,ah` / `rcr ebx,1` / `mov eax,ebx` loop from the LSD).  I have HT enabled (which is a pre-condition for SKL150 to manifest), but I was testing on a mostly-idle system so my thread had the core to itself.

With updated microcode, the LSD is completely disabled for everything all the time, not just when partial registers are active.  `lsd.uops` is always exactly zero, including for real programs not synthetic loops.  Hardware bugs (rather than microcode bugs) often require disabling a whole feature to fix.  This is why SKL-avx512 (SKX) is [reported to not have a loopback buffer](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(client)#.C2.B5OP-Fusion_.26_LSD).  Fortunately this is not a performance problem: SKL's increased uop-cache throughput over Broadwell can almost always keep up with issue/rename.

---

### Extra AH/BH/CH/DH latency:

- Reading AH when it's not dirty (renamed separately) adds an extra cycle of latency for both operands.  e.g. `add bl, ah` has a latency of 2c from input BL to output BL, so it can add latency to the critical path even if RAX and AH are not part of it.  (I've seen this kind of extra latency for the other operand before, with vector latency on Skylake, where an int/float delay "pollutes" a register forever.  TODO: write that up.)

This means unpacking bytes with `movzx ecx, al` / `movzx edx, ah` has extra latency vs. `movzx`/`shr eax,8`/`movzx`, but still better throughput.

- Reading AH when it *is* dirty doesn't add any latency.  (`add ah,ah` or `add ah,dh`/`add dh,ah` have 1c latency per add).  I haven't done a lot of testing to confirm this in many corner-cases.

**Hypothesis: a dirty high8 value is stored in the bottom of a physical register**.  Reading a clean high8 requires a shift to extract bits [15:8], but reading a dirty high8 can just take bits [7:0] of a physical register like a normal 8-bit register read.

Extra latency doesn't mean reduced throughput.  This program can run at 1 iter per 2 clocks, even though all the `add` instructions have 2c latency (from reading DH, which is not modified.)

```
global _start
_start:
    mov     ebp, 100000000
.loop:
    add ah, dh
    add bh, dh
    add ch, dh
    add al, dh
    add bl, dh
    add cl, dh
    add dl, dh

    dec ebp
    jnz .loop

    xor edi,edi
    mov eax,231   ; __NR_exit_group  from /usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h
    syscall       ; sys_exit_group(0)
```

```
 Performance counter stats for './testloop':

     48.943652      task-clock (msec)         #    0.997 CPUs utilized          
             1      context-switches          #    0.020 K/sec                  
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
             3      page-faults               #    0.061 K/sec                  
   200,314,806      cycles                    #    4.093 GHz                    
   100,024,930      branches                  # 2043.675 M/sec                  
   900,136,527      instructions              #    4.49  insn per cycle         
   800,219,617      uops_issued_any           # 16349.814 M/sec                 
   800,219,014      uops_executed_thread      # 16349.802 M/sec                 
         1,903      lsd_uops                  #    0.039 M/sec                  

   0.049107358 seconds time elapsed
```

---

**Some interesting test loop bodies**:

```
%if 1
     imul eax,eax
     mov  dh, al
     inc dh
     inc dh
     inc dh
;     add al, dl
    mov cl,dl
    movzx eax,cl
%endif

Runs at ~2.35c per iteration on both HSW and SKL.  reading `dl` has no dep on the `inc dh` result.  But using `movzx eax, dl` instead of `mov cl,dl` / `movzx eax,cl` causes a partial-register merge, and creates a loop-carried dep chain.  (8c per iteration).


%if 1
    imul  eax, eax
    imul  eax, eax
    imul  eax, eax
    imul  eax, eax
    imul  eax, eax         ; off the critical path unless there's a false dep

  %if 1
    test  ebx, ebx          ; independent of the imul results
    ;mov   ah, 123         ; dependent on RAX
    ;mov  eax,0           ; breaks the RAX dependency
    setz  ah              ; dependent on RAX
  %else
    mov   ah, bl          ; dep-breaking
  %endif

    add   ah, ah
    ;; ;inc   eax
;    sbb   eax,eax

    rcr   ebx, 1      ; dep on  add ah,ah  via CF
    mov   eax,ebx     ; clear AH-dirty

    ;; mov   [rdi], ah
    ;; movzx eax, byte [rdi]   ; clear AH-dirty, and remove dep on old value of RAX
    ;; add   ebx, eax          ; make the dep chain through AH loop-carried
%endif
```

The setcc version (with the `%if 1`) has 20c loop-carried latency, and runs from the LSD even though it has `setcc ah` and `add ah,ah`.

```
00000000004000e0 <_start.loop>:
  4000e0:       0f af c0                imul   eax,eax
  4000e3:       0f af c0                imul   eax,eax
  4000e6:       0f af c0                imul   eax,eax
  4000e9:       0f af c0                imul   eax,eax
  4000ec:       0f af c0                imul   eax,eax
  4000ef:       85 db                   test   ebx,ebx
  4000f1:       0f 94 d4                sete   ah
  4000f4:       00 e4                   add    ah,ah
  4000f6:       d1 db                   rcr    ebx,1
  4000f8:       89 d8                   mov    eax,ebx
  4000fa:       ff cd                   dec    ebp
  4000fc:       75 e2                   jne    4000e0 <_start.loop>

 Performance counter stats for './testloop' (4 runs):

       4565.851575      task-clock (msec)         #    1.000 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.08% )
                 4      context-switches          #    0.001 K/sec                    ( +-  5.88% )
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
                 3      page-faults               #    0.001 K/sec                  
    20,007,739,240      cycles                    #    4.382 GHz                      ( +-  0.00% )
     1,001,181,788      branches                  #  219.276 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
    12,006,455,028      instructions              #    0.60  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.00% )
    13,009,415,501      uops_issued_any           # 2849.286 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
    12,009,592,328      uops_executed_thread      # 2630.307 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
    13,055,852,774      lsd_uops                  # 2859.456 M/sec                    ( +-  0.29% )

       4.565914158 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.08% )
```

Unexplained: it runs from the LSD, even though it makes AH dirty.  (At least I think it does.  TODO: try adding some instructions that do something with `eax` before the `mov  eax,ebx` clears it.)

But with `mov ah, bl`, it runs in 5.0c per iteration (`imul` throughput bottleneck) on both HSW/SKL.  (The commented-out store/reload works, too, but SKL has faster store-forwarding than HSW, and it's [variable-latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442458/loop-with-function-call-faster-than-an-empty-loop/45529487#45529487)...)

```
 #  mov ah, bl   version
 5,009,785,393      cycles                    #    4.289 GHz                      ( +-  0.08% )
 1,000,315,930      branches                  #  856.373 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
11,001,728,338      instructions              #    2.20  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.00% )
12,003,003,708      uops_issued_any           # 10275.807 M/sec                   ( +-  0.00% )
11,002,974,066      uops_executed_thread      # 9419.678 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
         1,806      lsd_uops                  #    0.002 M/sec                    ( +-  3.88% )

   1.168238322 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.33% )
```

Notice that it doesn't run from the LSD anymore.

---

#### 2023 update

Some more tests, still on i7-6700k Skylake, this time with newer microcode (version 0xf0) that permanently disabled the LSD (because of AH-merging correctness issue in corner cases, apparently.)

```
.loop:
   times 6 mov ah, cl   ; or as low as times 3.  But times 7 makes the loop slower, 4c / iter
    mov ax, bx          ; trigger an AH merge
    dec ebp
    jnz .loop
.end:
```

- With `times 1` or `times 2`  `mov ah, cl`: 2 cycles / iter.
  (4 or 5 uops issued and executed / iter)
- With `times 3` to `times 6`  `mov ah, cl`: 3 cycles / iter
  (6 to 10 uops issued and executed)
- With `times 7` to `times 10`  `mov ah, cl`: 4 cycles / iter

The bottleneck with `mov ah, cl` is I think front-end throughput.
An AH-merging uop needing to issue in a cycle by itself would explain this, e.g. an upper limit of 5 uops in 2 cycles, with 4 in one cycle, 1 in the other.  And increasing by 1 cycle for each 4 more uops.  That front-end bubble for the AH-merging uop should give the uop cache time to keep up.

This also proves `mov ah, cl` doesn't depend on the old RAX after merge: if there was an output dependency, it couldn't run faster than 1 instruction per cycle (not counting the dec/jne).

But `xor ah,ah` or `mov ah,0` does create a loop-carried dependency chain, exactly like `inc ah`, confirming that `mov ax, bx` has a dependency on AH.  It limits speed to `n`+3 cycles per iteration, where `n` is the length of the `times n  mov ah,0` chain.  For example, `times 7` takes 10 cycles, with 10 uops issued and executed.  (From 10 instructions, including a macro-fused dec/jne, so there is an extra uop in there.)

It seems the latency cost of the AH-merging uop is 1 cycle, and the `mov ax, bx` itself costs another one cycle to merge a new value into the bottom of RAX.  The extra 1 cycle is coming when reading AH after writing RAX.  Adding a `mov ah, al` keeps the dependency on RAX, but without reading AH.

Comment: Do you have the firmware fix for the SKL150 erratum? There is some speculation it may change the LSD behavior in some or all cases, so it's worthwhile to note if the results above are pre or post firmware update.

Comment: That one has the fix, AFAIK.

Comment: This is great. Can you provide some more detail on how you're running the tests? I'm assuming this is using `perf` to some extent.

Comment: It would be good to introduce what you mean by "dirty `ah`". It just starts getting used, but the definition isn't clear. It seems to be something like "`ah` has been separately renamed, and not yet merged into the full reg". I also didn't understand _setcc ah depends on the old ah, but still dirties it._ Does "depends" here mean logically (I don't think it does?) or apparently falsely/performance-wise?

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Thanks for the editorial feedback.  I got frustrated with how long it was taking to write, and posted before doing a re-read of the whole answer once I had the question in good shape.  "Dirty AH" means a merge uop will be inserted if you `inc eax`.  The `setcc ah` dependency thing is an output dependency on AH, but not necessarily on the whole RAX.  So yes, it's a false dep preventing `setcc ah` from running at 2 per clock or from starting a new dep chain for something like `inc ah`.  I'll re-edit the answer soon.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: That detail is hidden in the question, where I mention that I use the same method as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all/44193770#44193770): assemble a static binary that does enough iterations of the loop to hide process-startup and `sys_exit()` overhead.

Comment: This is [x86] investigative journalism at its best. Thanks!

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Just double-checked: Arch Linux's `intel-ucode` package doesn't automatically enable microcode updates when you install it; you have to edit your bootloader config file.  I didn't have the fix while testing on SKL, but I didn't have two threads on one core.  I don't remember noticing any results where AH / LSD behaved differently on HSW vs. SKL.  When I have some time after next reboot, I'll re-test and see if there are any new cases where SKL won't use the LSD.

Comment: Something might have changed dramatically in this area for ICL. See [this ICL Instlat dump](https://github.com/InstLatx64/InstLatx64/blob/master/GenuineIntel00706E5_IceLakeY_InstLatX64.txt). It shows many of the instructions with `r8` destination suddenly at 1c throughput from the usual 0.25c or whatever depending on the operation. I don't know what mix of high and low registers are used in these tests, but in any case it seems like there might have been a big change here.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Oh wow, either InstLatx64 broke their tests and created a latency bottleneck, or ICL only runs stuff like `mov al, imm8` and `add al, bl` on one port (vs. any ALU port on Haswell and later to merge into the low 8 of a full reg).  That makes little sense; clang uses 8-bit operand size pretty carelessly so you'd expect this to be a measurable slowdown.  But `mov r16, r16` is still 0.25c throughput and it makes no sense to drop low-8 merging EUs but not low-16 from most ports.  I'd really like to see the same version of Instlat run on a Skylake to see if it's wrong there.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I doubt anything changed in all those test just before running it on ICL there: all the earlier dumps look normal in this respect. I'm thinking the tests may use say both `al` and `ah` for the T tests: this would have worked at full speed on contemporary chips as you describe above (ah renamed), but that something changed in ICL to limit this to one per cycle. I could be a *latency* effect, e.g., maybe they use 4 parallel chains and the latency went to 4 cycles which ends up showing up as T=1.

Comment: Check out `XCHG r1_8, r2_8` for more weirdness. The latency shot up to 4c and T improved to 0.33 - what? The other widths are unchanged.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: ok that's possible.  I'd certainly believe that AH/BH/CH/DH changed in ICL (like maybe not renaming them, or more penalty for using them), but I really hope InstLatx64 wasn't using them!  We can rule out 4 cycle latency for `add al, bl` and `mov al, imm8` - the latency test shows them as 1c.  I'm still almost certain the numbers are bogus *somehow* (probably accurately measuring badly-designed tests) so I'm not prepared to believe that `add r8, r8` really only has 1c throughput.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: we can see front-end bottlenecks from LCP stalls in `add ax, imm16` and some other non-`mov` imm16 instructions.  That's another possible source of error.  AH-merging can apparently cause a front-end delay on Haswell+ so maybe something like that is happening.

Comment: @PeterCordes - yeah I don't mean that `add al, bl` would have 4 cycle latency, but some combination of `ah` and `al` use would create a 4-cycle dependency chain, which wasn't a chain at all before. E.g., if `ah` isn't renamed, suddenly independent `ah` and `al` use which were independent 1-cycle chains would combine together into a 2 cycle chain at a minimum. If there are some penalties for using `ah`, the chain could be longer.

Comment: ... but yeah I don't think `add r8, r8` or the other instructions will really turn out to be 1T.

Comment: About the "Write-only access to ah with mov ah, r8" part - was this eliminated, i.e., not uop? You mention "These are both instructions that wouldn't normally need an ALU uop (for the 32-bit version)." but does the 8-bit version take a uop or not?

Comment: @BeeOnRope: good question, just tested and it's not eliminated.  Updated that bullet point.  It needs a p0156 uop.  A loop with 7 `mov ah, bl` and one dec/jnz runs at 2.001c / iter and basically saturates all 4 ALU ports, proving that it's really p0156 and no false dependency.

Comment: @PeterCordes Judgement question. For generic x86_64 code (thinking GLIBC's generic x86_64 `memcmp`) do you think it makes sense to avoid partial registers at the cost of code size or since all SnB+ handle it well (w.o a stall) it worth the bytes?

Comment: @Noah: If it's inside an important loop and would create a performance disaster on Nehalem or earlier (stalling the front-end for ~3 cycles), I think we should still avoid it.  There are still Nehalem and even Core2 systems around.  Especially if the gain is just code-size in bytes, not even uops.  In a function using AVX, that rules out pre-SnB, and SnB itself handles it ok.  (Modern Pentium / Celeron pre IceLake don't have AVX1 or 2 so they and Tremont etc. are the only recent CPUs using non-AVX versions of functions.  Bulldozer has AVX.  Except in a VM that doesn't pass through AVX.)

Comment: @PeterCordes makes sense. Thinking mostly in the context of replacing `subl $0xff, %eax; jnz` with `incb %al; jnz` (or 16-bit) or `movzbl (%rdi), %ecx; orl %ecx, %esi` with `movb (%rdi), %sil` on return values w.o false dependency. Guess the latter case actually saves an instruction. But `memcmp` can be called in a loop (i.e `qsort`) so some merit to protecting throughput in those cases.

Comment: @Noah: Ok yeah, should be safe in `memcmp-avx2-movbe.S`, no P6 CPUs  support AVX2.  So for example, `subl    $0xffff, %eax` (5 bytes) can be replaced with `incw %ax` (3 bytes), following `vpmovmskb %xmm2, %eax` in the `L(less_vec):` block.  Looks like replacing instructions that use `$VEC_MASK` would be harder, since you need a parameterized *register name* instead of a number.  Would make the code less readable even with a macro like `INC_VECSIZE(a)` which expands to `inc %al` or `inc %ax`  (The reg implies the suffix, but not vice versa, you can't `incb %a`

Comment: @PeterCordes not so concerned with `memcmp-avx2-movsb` as that's in the page cross case which is relatively cold (although I realize `L(zero)` shouldn't aligned, ill fix that this weekend). I'm refactoring [`memcmp`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/memcmp.S;h=e02a53ea1e245a37ce0a83247dfe957f070afb0b;hb=HEAD) so that we can drop the sse4/ssse3 versions. `memcmp` is the x86_64 generic impl so older targets need to be kept in mind. Leaving one partial register stall in the n={2,3} that I can't find a good way to avoid without causing the case to split a cache-line.

Comment: @PeterCordes Want to leave the code bloated verison in `memcmp-avx2-movsb`. Once I fix alignment of `L(zero)` target will be ideal code layout from icache and DSB/LSD perspective. Especially in cold cases tend to optimize more for ensuring minimum number of Icache lines are brought in.

Comment: @Noah: Yeah, good plan, that makes sense.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh wow, theres actually a full cache line to be saved in `memcmp-avx2-movbe` :)

Answer (score 9):

**Update: Possible evidence that IvyBridge still renames low16 / low8 registers separately from the full register, like Sandybridge but unlike Haswell and later.**

[InstLatX64](http://instlatx64.atw.hu/) results from SnB and IvB show 0.33c throughput for `movsx r16, r8` (as expected, `movsx` is never eliminated and there were only 3 ALUs before Haswell).

But apparently InstLat's `movsx r16, r8` test bottlenecks Haswell / Broadwell / Skylake at 1c throughput (see also [this bug report on the instlat github](https://github.com/InstLatx64/InstLatx64/issues/4)).  Probably by writing the same architectural register, creating a chain of merges.

(The actual throughput for that instruction with separate destination registers is 0.25c on my Skylake.  Tested with 7 `movsx` instructions writing to eax..edi and r10w/r11w, all reading from `cl`.  And a `dec ebp/jnz` as the loop branch to make an even 8 uop loop.)

If I'm guessing right about what created that 1c throughput result on CPUs *after* IvB, it's doing something like running a block of `movsx dx, al`.  And that can only run at more than 1 IPC on CPUs that rename `dx` separately from RDX instead of merging.  So we can conclude that IvB actually does still rename low8 / low16 registers separately from full registers, and it wasn't until Haswell that they dropped that.  (**But something is fishy here: if this explanation was right, we should see the same 1c throughput on AMD which doesn't rename partial registers.  But we don't, see below**.)

Results with ~0.33c throughput for the `movsx r16, r8` (and `movzx r16, r8`) tests:

- [IvB with AIDA64 build: 4.0.568.0 May 24 2013](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00306A9_IvyBridge_InstLatX64.txt)
- [IvB-E build: 4.3.764.0 Jul 10 2017](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00306E4_IvyBridgeE_InstLatX64.txt)
- [SnB-EP with a 2013 build](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00206D5_SandyBridgeEP_InstLatX64.txt)
- [SnB with a 2018 build](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00206A7_SandyBridge3_InstLatX64.txt).

Haswell results with a mysterious `0.58c` throughput for `movsx/zx r16, r8`:

- [A Haswell result](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00306C3_Haswell_InstLatX64.txt) with the same 4.3.764.0 Jul 10 2017 build of AIDA64
- [Haswell-E](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00306F2_HaswellE2_InstLatX64.txt) with a 2014 build

Other earlier and later Haswell (and CrystalWell) / Broadwell / Skylake results are all 1.0c throughput for those two tests.

- [HSW](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00306C3_HaswellXeon_InstLatX64.txt) with 4.1.570.0 Jun  5 2013, [BDW](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00306D4_Broadwell2_InstLatX64.txt) with 4.3.15787.0 Oct 12 2018, [BDW](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel0040671_BroadwellH_InstLatX64.txt) with 4.3.739.0 Mar 17 2017.

---

As I reported in the linked InstLat issue on github, the "latency" numbers for `movzx r32, r8` ignore mov-elimination, presumably testing like `movzx eax, al`.

Even worse, the newer versions of InstLatX64 with separate-registers versions of the test, like `MOVSX r1_32, r2_8`, show latency numbers below 1 cycle, like 0.3c for that MOV*SX* on Skylake.  This is total nonsense; I tested just to be sure.

The `MOVSX r1_16, r2_8` test does show 1c latency, so apparently they're just **measuring the latency of the output (false) dependency**.  (Which doesn't exist for 32-bit and wider outputs).

**But that `MOVSX r1_16, r2_8` test measured 1c latency [on Sandybridge](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00206A7_SandyBridge3_InstLatX64.txt) as well!**  So maybe my theory was wrong about what the `movsx r16, r8` test is telling us.

---

**[On Ryzen](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/AuthenticAMD0810F10_K17_Zen_InstLatX64_2.txt)** (AIDA64 build 4.3.781.0 Feb 21 2018), **which we know doesn't do any partial-register renaming at all**, the results don't show the 1c throughput effect that we'd expect if the test was really writing the same 16-bit register repeatedly.  I don't find it on any older AMD CPUs either, with older versions of InstLatX64, like K10 or Bulldozer-family.

```
## Instlat Zen tests of ... something?
  43 X86     :MOVSX r16, r8                L:   0.28ns=  1.0c  T:   0.11ns=  0.40c
  44 X86     :MOVSX r32, r8                L:   0.28ns=  1.0c  T:   0.07ns=  0.25c
  45 AMD64   :MOVSX r64, r8                L:   0.28ns=  1.0c  T:   0.12ns=  0.43c
  46 X86     :MOVSX r32, r16               L:   0.28ns=  1.0c  T:   0.12ns=  0.43c
  47 AMD64   :MOVSX r64, r16               L:   0.28ns=  1.0c  T:   0.13ns=  0.45c
  48 AMD64   :MOVSXD r64, r32              L:   0.28ns=  1.0c  T:   0.13ns=  0.45c
```

IDK why throughput isn't 0.25 for all of them; seems weird.  This might be a version of the 0.58c Haswell throughput effect.  MOVZX numbers are the same, with 0.25 throughput for the no-prefixes version that reads R8 and writes an R32.  Maybe there's a bottleneck on fetch/decode for larger instructions?  But `movsx r32, r16` is the same size as `movsx r32, r8`.

The separate-reg tests show the same pattern as on Intel, though, with 1c latency only for the one that has to merge.  MOVZX is the same.

```
## Instlat Zen separate-reg tests
2252 X86     :MOVSX r1_16, r2_8            L:   0.28ns=  1.0c  T:   0.08ns=  0.28c
2253 X86     :MOVSX r1_32, r2_8            L:   0.07ns=  0.3c  T:   0.07ns=  0.25c
2254 AMD64   :MOVSX r1_64, r2_8            L:   0.07ns=  0.3c  T:   0.07ns=  0.25c
2255 X86     :MOVSX r1_32, r2_16           L:   0.07ns=  0.3c  T:   0.07ns=  0.25c
```

Excavator results are also pretty similar to this, but of course lower throughput.

https://www.uops.info/table.html confirms that Zen+ has the expected 0.25c throughput (and 1c latency) for [`MOVSX_NOREX (R16, R8)`](https://www.uops.info/html-instr/MOVSX_NOREX_R16_R8.html), same as Instlat found with their separate-reg tests.

Perhaps InstLat's throughput test for `MOVSX r16, r8` (not `MOVSX r1_16, r2_8`) only uses 2 or 3 dep chains, which isn't enough for modern CPUs?  Or perhaps breaks the dep chain occasionally so OoO exec can overlap some?

Comment: It looks like Zen 3's behavior has changed a bit here. Zen 2 and below seem to have 0.25 inv throughput for `add r8, r8` but Zen 3 is 1.0. There are several other changes too. Apparently Zen 3 is much more hetrogeneous in its ALUs (i.e., most operations were available on all 4 ALUs in Zen 1,2 but many are available on fewer in Zen 3, so maybe the byte operations got demoted in that way?). There are also some suspect results like `CMP r8, r8` showing as `0.02` inverse throughput (i.e., 50 of these can execute per cycle).

Comment: [Link to 5900X results](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/AuthenticAMD/AuthenticAMD0A20F10_K19_Vermeer2_InstLatX64.txt).